# Trouble creating a tab delimited file with PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a tab delimited file with PHP and having some troubles. Basically my tabs, and line breaks ie `\t` and `\n` end up being printed out instead of converted to what they are supposed to be.

My code is simple:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM products';
$res = mysql_query($sql);

$page_print = 'id \t title \t description \t price';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $page_print .= $row['product_id'] . ' \t ' . $row['product_name'] . ' \t ' . strip_tags($row['product_content']) . ' \t ' . $row['product_price'] . '\n';
}

$page_print = sanitize_output($page_print);

$myFile = "products.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
$stringData = trim($page_print);
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to append them using double quotes (").

quote from [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and
>   escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they
>   occur in single quoted strings.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of writing your own code. You can use **fputcsv** function

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM products ';
$res = mysql_query($sql);

$myFile = "products.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
fputcsv($fh, array('id', 'title', 'description', 'price'), "\t");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
  fputcsv($fh, $row, "\t");
}

fclose($fh);
```

Comment: most clean answer imho. But also here the \t needs to be added using double quotes ("), so:
`fputcsv($fh, array('id', 'title', 'description', 'price'), "\t");`

Answer (score 6):

Use double quotes around `\t` and `\n`. You can also use `PHP_EOL` constant for end of line.

```
$page_print .= $row['product_id'] . " \t " . $row['product_name'] . " \t " . strip_tags($row['product_content']) . " \t " . $row['product_price'] . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 1):

use double quotes `"` instead of single `'`

```
$page_print .= $row['product_id'] . " \t " . $row['product_name'] . " \t " . strip_tags($row['product_content']) . " \t " . $row['product_price'] . "\n";
```

EDIT 1

surely you can also use [chr()](http://ch.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php)

```
$page_print .= $row['product_id'] . chr(9) . $row['product_name'] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

`\t` will be tab symbol in ouput only when using double quotes (`" "`) - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double